# How can I export data from oracle database to .mdb (MS access) file using pl/sql or Oracle Apex?

Tags: ms-access, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex, plsqldeveloper

Is there a way to export data from Oracle database 11g using PL/SQL or Oracle Apex to a .mdb extension file. I need this one to import it in access database. I mention that I have blob columns in the export data. Thank you.

Comment: That's a bit weird.  Normally, you'd configure Access to pull the data or generate something like a CSV file and let the user import that into Access or whatever other tool they have or use an ETL tool to load data into Access.  There are Java libraries that will generate MDB files.  You should be able to load one of those into your Oracle database, create a Java stored procedure that generates the file, and interface with that using PL/SQL.  If your database is on Windows, you can use C# rather than Java

Comment: you could probably have your acecss app read the data in from an oracle data source (just like excel, via ODBC)